# XML-based query extremely slow through ADO.NET, instant through SSMS

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssms

I'm in the perennial situation: a query that runs instantly through SSMS with a handful of reads, but slow enough to time out with thousands of reads when run through ADO.NET.  *Unlike* the other questions I could find on StackOverflow, clearing the query cache (or forcing myself to use the one SSMS uses) does not seem to be doing the trick.

Generally, when others have reported this situation on StackOverflow, they've had corrupt query caches.  In all of these cases, the fix has been either to run the ADO.NET queries with `SET ARITHABORT ON` (to match the session settings being used by SSMS) or to run `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` and `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to force the query cache to rebuild.  These techniques make no difference in my application, making me believe that there's something more fundamental going on.

The query in question is this (actual verbatim query captured by SQL Profiler, cleaned up only for formatting):

```
declare @p5 xml
set @p5=convert(xml,N'<r>
<n v="66ebc21b3bcb31e9a5ecbfb4b29fd2a47c37994c"/>
<n v="665919306fb23d9e685638a2d199e1e623745305"/>
<n v="a080c3b4e0c86e37b4d494d5efc09cebe20c6929"/>
<n v="245cb49bdeca9e37ef9bbd55877e21ade14e6282"/>
<n v="297650a6be65be332c1bb2aab426331a156ee342"/>
<n v="6a2668c8ab64fecf3b6925c7be613c61cef4dd7c"/>
<n v="09923f25f8b1de19f693bca1111bfa50d617856e"/>
<n v="0a7836d8e4e34f4ea92b2105eea5a99029949428"/></r>')
exec sp_executesql N'
            SELECT ixChangesetTag, ixRepo, ixChangeset, sTag, fBookmark
            FROM ChangesetTag
              INNER JOIN @p2.nodes(''/r/n'') X(n) ON X.n.value(''xs:hexBinary(@v)'', ''binary(20)'') = ixChangeset
            WHERE ixRepo = @p0 AND ixCustomer = @p1',N'@p0 bigint,@p1 int,@p2 xml',@p0=2,@p1=23363,@p2=@p5
```

(The XML parameter is in order to allow using a parameterized query where I'd normally have trouble doing so, since the number of objects I want to pass in varies.  Table-valued procedures would be the 2008 way to do this, but some of our customers run on 2005.)

Run through SSMS, the actual query plan used looks appropriate (index seeks), and takes about 200 reads over 4ms.  Run through the web application, it takes about 4500 reads over a second.

What am I missing here?  Could something be reinstating the bad query plan when run through the web application, despite the `DBCC` calls and `ARITHABORT` settings?

Comment: "it's a typical use-XML-to-do-a-parameterized-WHERE IN-clause hack" - run that one by me again?

Comment: BTW: "In all of these cases, the fix has been either to run the ADO.NET queries with SET ARITHABORT ON (to match the session settings being used by SSMS) or to run DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS and DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to force the query cache to rebuild" - none of those are actually fixes. That is treating the symptoms, and not the real cause.

Comment: @MitchWheat I cleaned up that explanation a tad.  This query replaced one with an arbitrary, potentially large number of elements in a `WHERE ixChangeset IN (...)` clause, allowing it to be parameterized and hit the query cache.

Comment: @MitchWheat And yeah, I know that `DBCC` and the like is treating the symptom, not the cause, but I'd hoped originally that setting `ARITHABORT OFF` in SSMS would at least give me the wrong query plan.  That sadly seems not to be the case.

Comment: Read this article written by Erland Sommarskog (SQL Server MVP): Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? (http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I have read that article, and have followed the advice best as I can (using the exact SQL, including variable definitions; checking the query plan where I can; etc.).  Is there something specific that you thought was appropriate?  The most helpful thing, seeing the bad plan, is something I can't easily figure out how to do, since it's not a sproc.

Comment: I have no explanation on the difference for you but in my experience the query optimizer can be a bit confused when mixing in XML stuff with a regular query so when I do this kind of multi parameter things I fill a table variable with the shredded XML and then use the table variable in the actual query.

Comment: @BenjaminPollack: Please run this query (https://gist.github.com/2217486) and publish the results. This query shows the settings for SSMS session and ASP.NET session. Replace <write ASP.NET session id> with the real ASP.NET session id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being that SQL Server was generally picking an absolutely horrible execution strategy, basically looping over the XML repeatedly, rather than doing a sane join.  The fix was to put the XML into a temporary table and join on *that* instead, which reliably yielded good execution plans.

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix would be to put a multi-column index on (ixCustomer, ixRepo, ixChangeset). Without knowing what the columns actually are, whether they are unique etc its hard to come up with a better answer.

Comment: Given that the query runs instantly when run from SSMS, I'm disinclined to believe this is an index issue.

Comment: @Benjamin Pollack - When you run from SMS it's picking a better index then when you run from code, probably do to some ambiguous charset setting or something .NET does differently then the default SMS session. If you do the multi-column index it will always be inclined to use it.